# Does placement of tokens in the Lexer matter?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

Is there any difference in either semantics or performance in where tokens are included in the `lexer file? For example:

```
EQUAL              :        '='      // Equal, also var:=val which is unsupported
NAMED_ARGUMENT     :        ':=';    // often used when calling custom Macro/Function
```

Vs.

```
NAMED_ARGUMENT     :        ':=';    // often used when calling custom Macro/Function
EQUAL              :        '='      // Equal, also var:=val which is unsupported
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, the order won’t matter.  If the Lexer finds `:=`, then it will generate a `NAMED_EQUAL` token (because it is a longer sequence of characters than `=`).

The Lexer will prefer the rule that matches the longest sequence of input characters.

The only time order matters is if multiple Lexer rules match the same length sequence of characters, and then the Lexer will generate a token for the first Lexer rule in the grammar (so, for example, be sure to put keywords before something like an `ID` rule, as it’s quite likely that your keyword will also match the `ID` rule, but by occurring before `ID`, the keyword will be selected.

-- EDIT --

All that said... as @rici mentions in his comment, in this *particular* case, order is unimportant for an entirely different reason.

The Lexer attempts to match input at the beginning of the file (or at the character after the last recognized token.

I think of it like this:  The Lexer chooses a character and then rules out all the Lexer rules that can't start with this character.  Then is looks at the sequence of that character and the next character and rules out all the Lexer rules that can't begin with that sequence of characters.  If does this repeatedly, until it has a sequence of characters that can't match any Lexer rule.  At that point, we know that everything up to (but excluding) that character had to match one or more Lexer rules.  If there's only one rule then that's the generated token.  *IF* there are multiple Lexer rules that matched, then the first one is selected.

In your case the ':' would have immediately ruled out a match of the `EQUAL` token (it can't begin with a ':'), but will still leave open the possibility that it might match the `NAMED_EQUAL` token.  If the next character is a '=' then it knows that it could match the `NAMED_EQUAL` rule (but maybe you have other rules that could start with ":=", so it looks at the next character (we'll guess it's a space).  ":+ "`does not match the`NAMED_EQUAL`rule, and for this example, doesn't match ANY rules.  Now it backs up and says ":+" matched the`NAMED_EQUALS`rule (and no others), so it creates a`NAMED_EQUALS` token, and starts the whole process again starting with the space that it's couldn't match.

Comment: `=` fails (if it fails) not because it is shorter but because it doesn't match. The lexical scanner always matches at the current input point, and that has a `:`, assuming that `:=` matches.